# Calculating Counterparty Exposure of a collateralized Portfolio

Tags: counterparty-risk

What could be counterparty exposure on a portfolio where:-

a. Client sells a put option on equity to us which is collateralized by corporate bond?

b. Client buys a put option on equity from us which is collateralized by corporate bond?

How will the exposure be calculated for both scenarios?

Comment: The client buys the put option or sells it?  I’m unclear.

Comment: Edited the question and included both scenarios